Biblatex bibliography fields ordering issue
I am facing a troubling problem while printing a bibliography entry for a book (@book) with a comment. My intention is to print the "note" field at the end, on a new line. However, the publisher's name and year currently appear at the end, causing the note to be squeezed between the title and the publisher's name.

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{F-K,
  author    = {Farkas-Kra},
  title     = {Riemann Surfaces},
  publisher = {Springer Verlag},
  series    = {GTM},
  volume    = {71},
  year      = {1980},
  keywords =  {GT},
  note      = {Modern, quite comprehensive, especially on the compact case, detailed study of automorphisms.}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage[
 natbib=true,
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{bib file}
\author{random}
\maketitle


\printbibliography[keyword={GT},title={General Theory}]
\nocite{*}


\end{document}


In biblatex note is for notes of bibliographic nature (it is mostly intended for publication data that does not fit into any other field) and thus placed in the middle of the entry. The addendum field is placed at the end of an entry and could be used here instead. See for example How to move the field note at the end of the reference.
The contents in your example, however, look as though semantically annotation would be the more appropriate field. biblatex actually has quite a sophisticated system that also allows you to load longer annotations from external files, but in your case the annotation field would be enough. Out of the box only the reading style supports this field, but it can be added to any other standard style (and most good contributed styles) as shown in Format "annotation" field in biblatex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true,
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \setunit{%
    \finentrypunct
    \renewcommand*{\finentry}{}%
    \par}%
  \usebibmacro{annotation}%
  \finentry
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{F-K,
  author     = {Farkas-Kra},
  title      = {Riemann Surfaces},
  publisher  = {Springer Verlag},
  series     = {GTM},
  number     = {71},
  year       = {1980},
  keywords   = {GT},
  annotation = {Modern, quite comprehensive, especially on the compact case,
                detailed study of automorphisms.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[keyword={GT},title={General Theory}]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}



You have to change Biblatex's bibliography style to fix this.
Start by trying the different premade styles to see if one of them does what you want.
If you are unlucky, you will have to dig the bibliography drivers machinery to get it.
For a 2023 version of Biblatex, if you look at section 4.2.3 Bibliography Drivers of Biblatex's documentation, you will see a simple example for the book entry driver, which tells LaTeX how to organize the different information in the output.

The drivers are declared in .bbx bibliography style files.
You can see the preinstalled ones in your LaTeX distribution folder, for example, mine are in /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/. You will see that they build from each other using the \RequireBibliographyStyle command, so you can use it to not recreate a style from scratch.
You can use your own local .bbx file by giving its name to the bibstyle= option of the Biblatex package at loading.
What you have to do is redefine the book driver and change its order.

The standard style uses the following driver:
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

You can copy and paste it (or the one of your selected style) to your custom .bbx to not start from scratch again.
Notice that it uses a mix of \print… and \usebibmacro commands interspersed in 'units' and 'blocks'; the macros are defined in the biblatex.def file in the same directory as bbx/ in the LaTeX distribution; units and blocks impact the separation punctuation and line breaks in the entry.
What you want to do is just displace the line \printfield{note}% to the end of the entry.

So in summary, You would have to create a local .bbx file that inherits from a pre-existing one with the \RequireBibliographyStyle command, with in it a copy of the book driver of the inherited style, modified to move the note field at the end, and tell Biblatex to use your file by specifying the bibstyle option of the package.

Alternatively, this is a bit simpler but less ordered, you can put the new driver in the local biblatex.cfg file, dropping the \RequireBibliographyStyle and the package option.
The file is automatically recognized and loaded by Biblatex, and overrides the package options.

Welcome to tex.sx.

Thanks, @barbarabeeton!
